# Unset does not work for session array

Tags: php, session

I want to remove the items from the shopping cart, but whenever I click on remove button for a item it just refreshes the page and nothing is removed.

When I again click the remove button the item is removed.

Example:
I have selected 3 items in cart.
If I click remove for 2nd item (`"ind_to_rem" =2`) then the page refreshes and does nothing. again if I click remove for 1st item, now the 2nd item is removed - i.e unset works for the previous item.
Then if click remove for 3rd item, the 1st item is removed - i.e the previous one.

```
if(isset($_POST["ind_to_rem"]) && $_POST["ind_to_rem"] != " ")
{
    $key_to_remove = $_POST["ind_to_rem"]; 
    if(isset($_SESSION["cart_array"])  && count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <=1)
    {
        unset($_SESSION['cart_array']);
    }
    else
    {
        unset($_SESSION['cart_array'][$key_to_remove]);
        //sort($_SESSION['cart_array']);
    }
}
```

The HTML relative to the `ind_to_rem` field:

```
$cartOutput .= '<td>
  <form action="cart.php" method="post">
  <input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" />
  <input name="ind_to_rem" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" />
  </form></td>'; 
$cartOutput.= "</tr>" ; $i++
```

Comment: Sounds to me like the issue here is with an index variable. Can you please show us the HTML relative to the `ind_to_rem` field?

Comment: $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="ind_to_rem" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
  $cartOutput.= "</tr>" ; 
  
  $i++;

Comment: Are you doing that after or before unsetting?

Comment: I think you are writting $cartOutput  before unseting, so changes will not be visible after another refresh.

Comment: Agreed with oscargilfc.

Comment: Thank you .. it worked . I was writing $cartOutput before unsetting

Comment: I have a another doubt .I have created a cart table .row 1 have the headings like s.no , product , desc , image ,price  and the following rows are populated using array . When i want to empty shopping cart ,unsetting the array happens and the products selected are removed and its working fine . But table's 1st row headings alone remains there . how to remove when the unsetting happens